# Using Sequelize to find all images by related keyword with an array of keyword ID values to include / exclude

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Node.js/Express/**Sequelize** project where I'm storing a library of images with related keywords, and I want to be able to search for images by those keywords.

I have an images table with a many-to-many relationship to keywords, and a keywords table with a many-to-many relationship to images.

```
Image.belongsToMany(Keywords, {
  as: 'keywords',
  through: {
    model: ImageKeywords,
    unique: false
  },
  foreignKey: 'image_id',
  constraints: false
});

Keywords.belongsToMany(Image, {
  as: 'image',
  through: {
    model: ImageKeywords,
    unique: false
  },
  foreignKey: 'keyword_id',
  constraints: false
});
```

I have an array of keyword IDs to search with using AND, and an array of keywords to exclude from the search using NOT. These are entered by the user via a search form, but essentially the following demonstrates the structure.

```
let keywordsAnd = [1,2,3]
let keywordsNot = [4,5,6]
```

For each image, I've associated one or many keywords through the join table, and can fetch images and display all of their keywords without any difficulty.

What I'm trying to accomplish is when a user enters a list of keywords they want to search for, and specifies some to exclude, I want to find all of the images using an AND search with the keywordsAnd array, and exclude those in the keywordsNot array.

For the above example, I want to return any image associated with all of the keywords with the IDs 1, 2 or 3, and excludes any of those images associated any of the keywords of ID 4, 5 or 6.

I was trying to use the following via the Keywords.findAll path:

```
   Keywords.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: Image,
            as: 'image',
            include: [{
                model: Keywords,
                as: 'keywords',
                attributes: ['id', 'name']
            }]
        }],
        where: { 
            id: {
                [Op.and]: [
                    keywordsAnd,
                    { [Op.not]: keywordsNot }
                ]
            }
        }
    })
```

This appears to do an OR search using the keywordsAnd array, and throws an error if keywordsNot is defined.

So with the above [1,2,3] array, I get all the images with the keyword IDs 1, 2 or 3.

It occurs to me that perhaps I should be searching through Image.findAll, including the Keywords model, but I'm not familiar enough with the mechanics of Sequelize at this point to know the correct approach and syntax, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can use `Image.findAll` instead `Keywords.findAll` as first query and within use `include` in order to create a join with Keywords in SQL query level.

Inside `include` you can add a `where` clause as you can see above in order to alter `Keywords` research.

Finally you can use `Op.in` and `Op.notIn`, both of them are used to work with arrays.

See [Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html) and put special attention to **Relations / Associations** and **Operators** sections.

I hope it helps!

```
Image.findAll({
  include: [ {
    model: Keywords,
    as: 'Keywords',
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    where: {
      id: {
        [Op.and]: [
          { [Op.in]: keywordsAnd },
          { [Op.notIn]: keywordsNot }
        ]
      }
    }
  } ]
});
```

Comment: The [Op.in] part of this is working, but the [Op.notIn] part doesn't exclude Images with keywords in the keywordsNot array. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.